# WhatsApp-API-client-Python, а может и другие библиотеки которые реализуют возможность звонков

Tags: python, api, whatsapp

Есть ли какие либо открытые api для whatsapp, которые позволяют осуществлять звонки через api? Интересует только возможность прозвона не обязательно что бы бот разговаривал, просто кратковременный звонок который звони и сразу же сбрасывает.